# Parsing a a list of nested dicts in Python

Tags: python, json, nested

i m trying to parse this json string that looks like this. i tried `pd.Dataframe(PayloadData['gsmRegistrationInfo']` but i got this error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

```
[{'gsmRegistrationInfo': [{'timestamp': {'secondsSince20000101': 695570408},
    'countryAndOperatorCode': 310410,
    'cellNumber': 170003217,
    'locationAreaCode': 35634,
    'networkType': 4,
    'registered': 1}]
```

Comment: Are you certain that's a json string and not already parsed object?

Comment: seems like it might already be an object then.

Comment: actually ya it is already a decoded string

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import ChainMap


    multiDct_to_single=[]
    for i in range(len(df['gsmRegistrationInfo'])):
        qq=dict(ChainMap(*df['gsmRegistrationInfo'][i][::-1])) # notice the star!
        multiDct_to_single.append(qq)
    
    
    data = pd.DataFrame(multiDct_to_single).head()
```